# Can I Use NSPredicate with NSSet

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, nsset

i want to get intersect of two NSSet, by default NSSset compare every member of object for concluding intersection objects in SetA and SetB.

here is my code.

```
NSMutableDictionary *dic = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
[dic setObject:@"25" forKey:@"age"];
[dic setObject:@"abc" forKey:@"Name"];

NSMutableDictionary *dic1 = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
[dic1 setObject:@"21" forKey:@"age"];
[dic1 setObject:@"xyz" forKey:@"Name"];

NSMutableDictionary *dic2 = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
[dic2 setObject:@"20" forKey:@"age"];
[dic2 setObject:@"abc" forKey:@"Name"];

NSMutableDictionary *dic3 = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
[dic3 setObject:@"25" forKey:@"age"];
[dic3 setObject:@"abcNameNotMatch" forKey:@"Name"];

NSMutableDictionary *dic4 = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
[dic3 setObject:@"20" forKey:@"age"];
[dic3 setObject:@"abcNameNotMatch" forKey:@"Name"];

NSArray *a = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:dic,dic1,dic2, nil];
NSArray *b = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:dic3,dic4, nil];

NSMutableSet *setA = [NSMutableSet setWithArray:a];
NSSet *setB = [NSSet setWithArray:b];
//[setA intersectSet:setB];
//NSLog(@"c: %@", [setA allObjects]);

[setA intersectSet:setB];

NSLog(@"d: %@", [setA allObjects]);
```

I want to get filter object(intersect) only on the basis of age. in Short, can i specify that intersectSet function should compare only age of SetA and SetB.MeanWhile, ignore values of name. 
2 object should be return dic and dic2 by using my code.
intersecting objects in setA and setB is. 
for help.

setA

1)dic age is 25

2)dic2 age is 20

setB

1)dic3 age is 25

2)dic4 age is 20

Comment: i don't know maybe you can intersect with speicific key. but you can do one thing. use `unionSet` and you'll get all data in one array then you can apply predicate for key using `[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"age = '25'"]`. i don't know if other solution is available.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"age in %@.age", setB];
NSSet *result =  [setA filteredSetUsingPredicate:predicate];
```

If you want to modify `setA` itself, use:

```
[setA filterUsingPredicate:predicate];
```

---

example:

```
NSMutableSet *setA = [NSMutableSet setWithArray:
                      @[
                        @{@"age":@(11), @"Name":@"abc"},
                        @{@"age":@(11), @"Name":@"def"},
                        @{@"age":@(22), @"Name":@"ghi"},
                        @{@"age":@(22), @"Name":@"jkl"},
                        @{@"age":@(33), @"Name":@"lmn"},
                        @{@"age":@(33), @"Name":@"opq"},
                        ]];
NSSet *setB = [NSSet setWithArray:
               @[
                 @{@"age":@(11), @"Name":@"rst"},
                 @{@"age":@(22), @"Name":@"uvw"},
                 @{@"age":@(22), @"Name":@"xyz"},
                 ]];

NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"age in %@.age", setB];
[setA filterUsingPredicate:predicate];
NSLog(@"%@", setA);
```

output:

```
{(
        {
        Name = abc;
        age = 11;
    },
        {
        Name = def;
        age = 11;
    },
        {
        Name = ghi;
        age = 22;
    },
        {
        Name = jkl;
        age = 22;
    }
)}
```

Comment: but it's working for only first found object in setB.even if two object age is same in setB it returns only one first match object.

Comment: You want values from `setB` also? Hmm... let me think.

Comment: no values from setB. but, if setB has two matching object in setA, then result should have two object. not only first match object in setA

Comment: i have modified my question see once more. thanx

Comment: I added the result example to the answer. Isn't that what you want?

Comment: He probably wants 11-rst, 22-uvw and 22-xyz to, as that would be the intersection of both dictionaries, based on the age value

Answer (score 0):

You could write a specific 'wrapper'-class for this problem and override the `isEqual:` and `hash:` methods.

Have it check for equality using the dictionaries age key. Put the wrappers in sets and intersect.